# Mapbox view lead to using more than 150 MB

Tags: ios, mapbox

I embedded `MGLMapView` into my iOS app. It works great except I noticed that the whole size of used memory now is more than 150 MB. Is it normal? How is it possible to decrease the amount of memory in use?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MapBox has an article explaining a size of a framework.

[Understanding iOS framework size](https://www.mapbox.com/help/ios-framework-size/)

The framework contains configurations for all iOS device architectures and simulators. However, when the user will install an app, he will get only configurations necessary for his device.

I've performed following steps to check real size off my app:

- connected my iPhone (real device) to XCode
- installed app
- went to **Settings > General > iPhone Storage** and found my app in the list.

Project size was **211 MB**, but installed app size was **124 MB**.

(test was performed with XCode 9.2 and iPhone 7 with iOS 11.2.1)